# C# Prevent Same-Name Properties in Child Class If Already In Parent Class

Tags: c#

Is it possible to prevent a child class from having the same property name as a parent class?

For example:

```
public class Vehicle {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Make { get; set; } // Honda, etc.
}

public class Car : Vehicle {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public bool HasWarranty { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like the above to throw a build error saying that `Vehicle` already has a property named `Title`. Is this possible? If another developer on my team does a copy/paste from `Car` to make a `Motorcycle` class and decides to a `Make` property, while `Vehicle` already has `Make` as a property name, it feels like a DRY violation.

Comment: Not satisfied with the warning to add a `new` modifier?

Comment: You can use the `sealed` keyword on class members (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members).  I think that should do the trick

Comment: @Flydog57, `sealed` prevents override, which doesn't relate to the OP's situation since none of his properties are abstract or virtual.  If they were, it still wouldn't do anything, since you can always hide the inherited property.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Thanks.  I should have fired up VS to check before I added my $0.02.

Comment: "Treat warnings as errors"? "Treat CS0108 as error"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings

Comment: *f another developer on my team does* - that's what code review is for.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to enforce something like this is with Attributes. You can create the concept of having custom validations that run against your codebase on wakeup of your application.

Pseudo Code:

```
public abstract ValidationAttribute : Attibute
{
    public abstract bool Validate(Type target);
}

------

public EnforceDistinctMembersAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    string[] members;

    public EnforceDistinctMembersAttribute(params string[] members)
    {
        this.members = members;
    }

    public override bool Validate(Type target)
    {
        if (target......
    }
}
```

Create a method that will loop over all types, find all `ValidationAttribute`s and call the `Validate` method of each one passing in the Type it was attached to. If you come across an issue, you can throw an exception or log or so on.

Remember this is only pseudo code and its only meant to get the idea across.

Usage:

```
[EnforceDistinctMembers] // or
[EnforceDistinctMembers(nameof(Title), nameof(Make))]
public class Vehicle {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Make { get; set; } // Honda, etc.
}

public class Car : Vehicle {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public bool HasWarranty { get; set; }
}
```